# Traveling from Mumbai to Berlin, connecting via Munich. Short-ish layover with immigration. Enough?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, short-connections, lufthansa, muc

I apologize if this kind of question has been asked again, but I am confused with some conflicting information and would appreciate some correct advice.

I am travelling on Lufthansa flights from Mumbai to Berlin via Munich (same ticket), with a layover of 1h 20 min in Munich. I arrive in Munich on a Friday at 5:40 AM via LH 767 and my departing flight to Berlin is LH 2030 at 7 AM.

Almost every piece of information I read online says that I will need to go through Immigration at Munich airport and customs at Berlin airport. However, when I called the Lufthansa agent to book the tickets, they told me BOTH immigration and customs will only happen in Berlin, and that Munich would just be a gate-to-gate transfer.

So my questions are

1) Where exactly would I be clearing immigration? Munich or Berlin?

2) Given the above answer, is a layover of 1h 20 min enough to make a transfer?

3) If I don't make the connection, I read that they would book me on the next flight. By next flight do they mean the next available flight, or the same flight but the next day? 
I really don't want it to be the latter, since I am only in Berlin for a couple of days and flying out on Sunday to Boston.

Helpful advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The [tag:flixbus] is super cheap and has several departures between Münich and Berlin every day - if you miss your connection and don't want to wait.

Comment: This is extremely bad advice because his bags will be through checked and you can't get to them if you are already outside. Also who wants to sit seven hours in a bus after an eight hour flight? You will surely get there faster if you just let Lufthansa take care of you, there's a flight every hour, most days even more frequent than that.

Comment: Munich is a very efficient airport. Your transit time is more than enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Where exactly would I be clearing immigration?

Munich. The LH agent must have misunderstood something. The MUC-TXL flight is an in-Schengen flight and there are no facilities to separate people cleared to be in Schengen and those who haven't so you must be cleared first. Your bags go all the way through, you will pick them up in Berlin, maybe that's what the agent told you about.

> Given the above answer, is a layover of 1h 20 min enough to make a transfer?

Yes, Munich is one of the most efficient airports, with just 30 minutes minimum connection times, it was specifically built for short connection times and Lufthansa has a hand in running the airport, too (very rare) and so it stays like that. 1:20 is plenty in Munich.

> By next flight do they mean the next available flight,

Exactly that. There are so many flights I'd expect at least one per hour but since you are flying in the morning, even more frequent is possible depending on which day.

Note: " or the same flight but the next day? " couldn't work in practice, not every flight is daily, some flights run on a specific day (for example, every Tuesday) or days (for example, every Wednesday and Saturday). Even worse the flight might just never fly again because the schedule changes the next day for example at season boundaries. Also, the rule is there to help the stranded customer not to frustrate them even more, missing a flight is bad enough.

Comment: Thanks. This is so helpful! I feel relieved now.

Comment: I too thought the LH agent is misunderstanding something, I reiterated my query a second time and he still said that Immigration would happen in Berlin. I got confused by that and decided to post here to get some help. Thanks again!

Comment: Check my recent [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144826/4188) on what to do if you do miss flight.